# Platform.runLater too slow in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, platform

I'm trying to execute a thread inside my JavaFx application and I also need to update my listview, reason why I used a Platform.runLater inside it. The problem is that it seems to be too slow, since it jumps the if state inside it. The `listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());` part is executed without problem, but ignore the the condition even if when I print the two value I wanna compare they are different. How can I improve it? Because I cannot move that `if` outside the Platform since I'm trying to display it in a thread of my JavaFX application.

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int currentOnServer = model.askNumbOfEmail();
                    if (emailForClient != currentOnServer) {
                        model.reLoadData();
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());
                            if (currentOnServer > emailForClient) {
                                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Hai recevuto un email!").showAndWait();
                            }
                        });
                        emailForClient = currentOnServer;
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    System.out.println("ParseException ERROR!");
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this `The problem is that it seems to be too slow, since it jumps the if state inside it. The listView.setItems(model.getEmailList()); part is executed without problem, but ignore the the condition even if when I print the two value I wanna compare they are different.` Can you explain it in a different way?

Comment: Do you mean you believe it takes too long to execute, and so by the time it gets to the line `if (currentOnServer > emailForClient)` it is no longer true? If so - this is a common issue when working with multiple threads, and you have to account for it when writing code. One way is by using `synchronized` or some monitor/latch from `java.util.concurent`, although in this instance you could introduce a `final boolean` variable that gets the value *before* the call to `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: @Gnas I'm pretty sure it jumps the if statement without any reason, I printed the two values right before it and they are different, so why not entering into the statement?

Comment: @JimBelushi2 I understand your problem now, see my answer for detail. Your title is very misleading by the way.

Comment: If you ever worry about one thread being too slow/too fast, you need to change the implementation. For concurrent threads you need to make sure that even if a thread runs arbitrary slow/fast, the result is correct; relying on timing may result in your program failing and those issues are hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement doesn't work because you're changing part of the condition in a separate thread:

`emailForClient = currentOnServer`

This is a common problem when you're working with threads. You need to modify the logic of your code to facilitate parallel execution. You can create a temp variable to store `emailForClient` and use it inside `Platform.runLater` instead:

```
model.reLoadData();
final int currentEmail = emailForClient; // I'm assuming emailForClient is an int

Platform.runLater(() -> {
    listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());

    if (currentOnServer > currentEmail) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Hai recevuto un email!").showAndWait();
    }
});

emailForClient = currentOnServer;
```